# Setting up Hadoop Client on Mac OS X

Tags: hadoop, osx-mavericks, cloudera-cdh

Currently, I have 3-node cluster running CDH 5.0 using MRv1.  I am trying to figure out how to setup Hadoop on my Mac.  So, I can submit jobs to the cluster.  According to the "Managing Hadoop API Dependencies in CDH 5", you just need the files in `/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*`  Do I need the following files too?  Does Cloudera has `hadoop-client` in tarball?

```
- core-site.xml
- hdfs-site.xml
- mapred-site.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'nk you can make use of cloudera tarball for setting up hadoop client, the same can be downloaded from the following path, configuration files are availble under etc/hadoop/ directory under Hadoop, just need to modify those files according to your environment.

http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop-2.2.0-cdh5.0.0-beta-2.tar.gz

If the above link doesn't match your version, use the following link for getting the available hadoop versions

http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/